# How to continue a sharepoint workflow after an error?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow, ms-project-server-2010

Is it possible to make a workflow progress to the next step after an error? Assuming that the error cause was fixed.
I don't want to restart the workflow from the first stage as I would loose the stage start and end timestamps and the approval items would be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure proper error handling in your workflow. There is no other way.